# Code isn't calculating decimal places

Tags: vba, excel, decimal, strikethrough

I'm trying to make a VBA module to sum cells excluding cells with a strikethrough. The code I'm using below works great, but will not calculate decimals. For instance, '5 + 5.50' will equal `10.00` I want to the code to keep decimals values up to two decimal places so that the sum above would be `10.50`.

```
Public Function ExcStrike(pWorkRng As Range) As Long
'Update 20140819
Application.Volatile
Dim pRng As Range
Dim xOut As Long
xOut = 0
For Each pRng In pWorkRng
If Not pRng.Font.Strikethrough Then
xOut = xOut + pRng.Value
End If
Next
ExcStrike = xOut
End Function
```

Comment: This just took a bit of learning... solution was to change 'As Long' to 'As Single' Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of an answer:

The Long data type contains integer numbers.

per OP:

> solution was to change 'As Long' to 'As Single'

I suppose I should add a little detail about [Single](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xay7978z.aspx)

> Holds signed IEEE 32-bit (4-byte) single-precision floating-point numbers ranging in value from -3.4028235E+38 through -1.401298E-45 for negative values and from 1.401298E-45 through 3.4028235E+38 for positive values. Single-precision numbers store an approximation of a real number.